# Using Principal Component Analysis to determine variable interaction

Tags: pca

I'm characterizing a communication channel by measuring bit error rate (ber) as a function of 15 channel settings: ber = Func(settings[1:15]). The dataset is about 100,000 samples.

I wonder if I can use PCA to explore interaction of settings and their effect on the bit error rate. Specifically:

1. How to prepare data for PCA; do I run PCA on {ber, settings[1:15]}, or only on settings[1:15] ?
   I've seen PCA used on "symmetric" data, such as images, text, etc.
2. What do projections of settings[1:15] on principal components tell me in this case
3. What do outlier datapoints in principal component space tell me.

Answer (score 2):

Principal Component Analysis is an unsupervised method -- that is, you use it on independent variables, `settings` in your case.

Once you have your principal components, you can partition the variance of your independent variables into orthogonal projections. That is, a certain amount of variance goes into component 1 (which is a linear combination of your variables), which is orthogonal to (uncorrelated with, but [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12128/what-does-orthogonal-mean-in-the-context-of-statistics)) the other components.

Usually, one uses PCA to replace a large number of variables by a much smaller number of principal components that are (i) uncorrelated and (ii) contain most of the variance.

However, given that you have a large number of samples and only a small number of variables, and given that you have a dependent variable, and given that you want to "explore interaction of settings and their effect on the bit error rate", I don't think PCA is the right method for you. You should consider either linear modelling, linear discriminant analysis, or maybe a method like PLS (which is to PCA what linear regression is to calculation of a mean). Or even a supervised machine learning method (like SVM, random forests, PLS-DA).