# Statistically orthogonal - explanation?

Tags: experiment-design, descriptive-statistics, orthogonal

I did see the related [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12128/what-does-orthogonal-mean-in-the-context-of-statistics) here but my question is more related to the actual explanation of the orthogonality itself.

So the following design is orthogonal (this is a latin square to be precise):

```
1234
2341
3412
4123
```

As noted in one of the afore mentioned answers:

"An experimental design is orthogonal if the effects of any factor balance out (sum to zero) across the effects of the other factors."

Can that be demonstrated on the design above? I still cannot see how that is orthogonal (and from a comment it should be immediately obvious when you look at it).

Comment: That was stated in a few books showing a latin square. The authors stated that it is immediately obvious that rows and columns are orthogonal to treatments. And that is exactly point of my question - I do not see that obvious!

Comment: Why would you assume it should be "immediately obvious"? Latin square designs are actually quite complicated to formulate mathematically. The statistical concept of "orthogonality" is closely related to orthogonality of vectors and to statistical independence. If you want an explanation of "orthogonality", there are much easier ways to explain it than by way of a Latin square experiment! It would be helpful if you clarified whether you are after an explanation of orthogonality in general or of Latin squares in particular.

Comment: Well, it may become obvious after a few pages of mathematical derivations. You are perhaps taking the book authors' comment somewhat out of context.

Comment: No, surely not. It is a book dealing with entirely different topic and there is just one page mentioning latin squares. Then there is a sample picture of a square and the comment that "you can immediately see that rows and columns are ortogonal to treatments". In another book, there is an explanation "because each treatment appears once in each row" - but to me that is not an explanation of why it is orthogonal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand you have four row levels, four column levels and the third factor has four levels (1, 2, 3, 4). In total, there are 16 observations.

The model is:

$${\vec Y}_{ijk} = \alpha + \sum_{i=1}^4\alpha_i^{A}{\vec v}_i +  \sum_{j=1}^4\alpha_i^{B}{\vec w}_j +   \sum_{k=1}^4\alpha_k^{C}{\vec z}_k   $$

where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are respectively row, column and the third ("latin letter") factor. Vectors ${\vec v}_i$, ${\vec w}_j$ and ${\vec z}_k$ are such that contain 1 at positions corresponding to combinations of factors present in the design. For instance, you have an experiment in which $A=2$ (second row), $B=2$ (second column) and $C=3$, so in the same position occupied by 
$Y_{223}$ in vector ${\vec Y}_{ijk}$, vectors ${\vec v}_2$, ${\vec w}_2$ and
${\vec z}_3$ would have 1 and all the others 0.

Now if the usual constraints $\sum_{i=1}^4\alpha_i^{A} = \sum_{j=1}^4\alpha_j^{B} = \sum_{k=1}^4\alpha_k^{C} = 0$ are forced upon the coefficients, it is easy to see that any inner product such as

$$< {\vec v}_i, \sum_{k=1}^4\alpha_k^{C}{\vec z}_k>$$

will be necessarily zero. The "ones" in ${\vec  v}_i$ multiply the "ones" in ${\vec z}_k$ only once for each $k$, so:

$$< {\vec v}_i, \sum_{k=1}^4\alpha_k^{C}{\vec z}_k>  = \sum_{k=1}^4\alpha_k^{C}<{\vec v}_i,{\vec z}_k> = \sum_{k=1}^4\alpha_k^{C} = 0$$

the last equality because of the zero sum constraint on the coefficients.

**EDIT (in response of comment):**

It would require much writing to answer using your example (and would perhaps not fit across the page) so let us imagine a simpler case:

```
12
21
```

that is, two row, column, and "latin letter" levels. The response vector and the design matrix would be as follows:
$$
\pmatrix{Y_{111} \\ Y_{122} \\ Y_{212} \\ Y_{221} } 
=
\pmatrix{
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \cr
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \cr
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 }
$$

The columns of the matrix are respectively $v_1$, $v_2$. $w_1$, $w_2$, $z_1$ and $z_2$. So you see for instance that facing $Y_{212}$ (=in the same row)  you have "ones" in vectors $v_2$, $w_1$ and $z_2$. That's what I meant.

Let me add that this is something which doesn't lend itself to lengthy explanations online. I suggest you look at some of the (many) good books on this topic. My favourite is Seber's book (I used much the first edition, but there is now a [second one](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471415405.html)). HTH.

**Further EDIT:**

Consider for instance $\alpha^B_1 = - \alpha^B_2 = 0.4$ so they add up to zero as required by the constraint. Then,

$$ <{\vec v}_1, \sum_{k=1}^4\alpha_k^{B}{\vec w}_k>  =  <\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 & 0}, 0.4\pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\0} - 0.4\pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 0\\ 1}> = 0.
$$
HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. And in the design matrix, how the orthogonality is now shown? Because when I multiply two column vectors, only the neighoubing ones have product=0.

Comment: Vectors in each block are directly orthogonal. Any vector in one block is orthogonal to feasible (=with coefficients satisfying the zero-sum constraint) linear combinations of vectors in any other block. "Block orthogonality" would perhaps be a better description of what is going on.

Comment: Could you please show on the sample design matrix in your example? What you mean by block and what vectors you combine with to show the zeru sum.

Comment: I wil further edit answer.

Comment: I see I am missing some basics, I have no idea how you arrived to 0,4 (what is meant by the alpha)

Comment: 0.4 is just an example value. The alphas are just the coefficients of the regressors, which in ANOVA happen to be vectors of  0's or 1s. Yes, I think some reading would help you.

Comment: Thank you. So going back to the original question - some authors mentioned that the orthogonality is obvious immediately by looking on the design because each treatment occurs exactly once for each factor. Is this what your approach would confirm?

Comment: Each level of each treatment occurs exactly once for each combination of levels of the other two treatments. That happens in the latin square. More generally, in other designs, the crucial notion is balance. For instance, in a two-way ANOVA (two treatments) the design would be balanced if each combination of levels is tested the same number of times (not necessarily once each). If you had, say two fertilizers and three types of cultivation, then a balanced design would call for the same number of observations of each combination fertilizer-type of cultivation. Balanced designs are orthogonal.

Comment: I do not think it occurs exactly once for each combination of levels of the other two treatments, that would be 3x3x3. In latin square, every treatment occurs once for both of remaining factors levels, but not for their combinations. But again, maybe I misunderstood the language

Comment: That's correct, you are right. What I described would be a 2-way complete design without replication. Still the latin square preserves orthogonality even though it is an incomplete design: it has some sort of balance, with each "letter" combined the same number of times with each of the row or column levels.

Comment: Thank you. So the orthogonality in this sense means that each effect is tested with every other effect independently? I still try to understand the orthogonality in this sense

Comment: It is rather a consequence of that. It means that you decompose the vector of values of the response into fragments which are projections into mutually orthogonal subspaces. This buys you a lot: the estimates of row, column, etc. effects are independent of each other. Lacking orthogonality, you cannot speak of e.g. column effect, as it would be dependent on whether or not the other effects are present.

Comment: Oh, well so that was exactly what I wanted to find out by asking my question. I suppose I should ask another one to address what you just mentioned. This is what I was looking for.