# Does X orthogonal to Z and Y orthogonal to Z imply XY orthogonal to Z?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Assume X orthogonal to Z and Y orthogonal to Z (but X and Y potentially correlated), can you conclude T=XY orthogonal to Z ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "orthogonal"?  A result like the one you inquire about is plausible when it means *independent* but otherwise is not.

Answer (score 4):

No, one cannot conclude that.

Let $ X = \{-1, 0, 1 \}$ with equal probability;

$Y = 2X$;

$Z = X^2$

$Cov(X,Z) = 0 $

$Cov(Y,Z) = 0 $

$Cov(XY,Z) \neq 0 $

Helpful Links:

- [Linear Independence, Orthogonality, Uncorrelated](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Linearly-Independent%2C-Orthogonal%2C-and-Uncorrelated-Rodgers-Nicewander/177dc3b719fdb7b2c01d6c341e0bd58a09a47a83/figure/0)
- [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12128/what-does-orthogonal-mean-in-the-context-of-statistics#:%7E:text=%40probability%20%22Orthogonal%22%20has%20meaning,Q(w%2Cw).)

Answer (score 3):

No, assume $Y=X$ be [Rademacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution) distributed, and $Z$ is independent of others having non-zero mean. Then , $E[XYZ]\neq 0$.

Comment: This is not a counterexample - $\mathbb{E}[XYZ] - \mathbb{E}[XY] \mathbb{E}[Z] = 0$ in this  case. (Equivalently, $XY$ is a constant, which is of course uncorrelated to anything. Or - $Z$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$, and so of $XY$, and so has to be uncorrelated to $XY$).

Comment: orthogonality does not mean uncorrelated

Comment: I guess you're right. Also, on re-reading, I find my comment above quite obnoxious. My apologies.

Comment: not at all, it's a discussion

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No.  Consider this counter-example:

Let $Z$ take on 4 possible values $(2, 1, -1, 2)$ with equal probability of 0.25.

Let $X = 1, 0, 1, \frac12$ when $Z = 2, 1, -1, 2$ respectively. Let $Y = X$.

Easy to show that $Cov(X, Z) = E(XZ) = 0$ and likewise $Cov(Y, Z) = E(YZ) = 0$, but
$Cov(XY, Z) = E(X^2Z) \ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I could be completely misunderstanding this, but consider a book. The spine is orthogonal to the base of the pages, but you can open the book to (almost any angle).